# Limt AWS API Gateway endpoint with GET parameters

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, aws-lambda, endpoint, aws-api-gateway

I have an API Gateway endpoint at some url, like this:

```
https://api.myapp.com/myendpoint
```

The people and/or services that are going to be accessing this endpoint need to pass particular parameters and values to the endpoint. Like this:

```
https://api.myapp.com/myendpoint?token=123456
```

Is it possible to limit access to the endpoint if the `token` parameter is missing OR if the `token` value is not a specific pre-determined value? Can I setup my endpoint to simply ignore calls that don't have the proper token?

I'm planning on using Lambda as the backend. Do I have to deal with this in my Lambda function? Ultimately, I'm trying to avoid unnecessary Lambda and API Gateway usage costs by random individuals making bogus calls to the endpoint. So if I can have API Gateway simply ignore these calls without spinning up Lambda that would be ideal.

If I am able to have API Gateway ignore these calls, do I still get billed for usage when bogus calls are made to the endpoint(s) that are missing the token?

The reason I'm asking is because the 3rd party service that is going to access this endpoint does not have any options for passing authentication parameters in headers or using AWS Cognito, etc. So I'm just trying to think of a simple way to limit access.

Comment: Does the 3rd party service let you specify the path?  I wonder if you could make a token as part of the path.

Comment: I am not seeing anything in documentation that would really get you to your end goal.  They really only seem to support header based strategies. The path idea might work by making your token kinda like a resource but that's really not providing you much value.  Then again I am not sure a query_string param will provide much value/security either.  So maybe an early return from your lambda process is your best bet given your constraints. That will at least save you some lambda costs.  Might want to double/triple check the service to see if they support headers or SSL certs.

Comment: I can specify the path the 3rd party uses yes. I'm thinking about coming up with a unique path with some hash or something in it, and then, on a regular basis, programmatically telling the 3rd party service to use a different path with a new hash in the url. That would make it nearly impossible for anyone to guess the endpoint url, since it's changing every day, or every hour or whatever.

Comment: Yea. That's what I was thinking as well. Good luck with it. Post anything interesting you learn.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to perform this validation in Lambda.

If you have a mapping for a query parameter `token` to the integration endpoint, then for a request like  `...?token=123` API Gateway will pass the parameter to the endpoint, but for `...?token=`, API Gateway will not.

API gateway does not do validation of query parameters like you want and you will be billed for the requests.

Comment: Are you saying that you can use mapping in order to set API Gateway to require `?token=123` in the request so that a variation like `?token=abc` would be ignored?